# How to upgrade PHP function parameters work with new Zend API?

Tags: php-extension, php-internals, php-7

I am working on a php extension to upgrade it to PHP7, my question is about `INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS`. In the previous version it is defined as:

`INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS int ht, zval *return_value, zval **return_value_ptr, zval *this_ptr, int return_value_used TSRMLS_DC`

and in the new zend engine it is defined as:

`INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS zend_execute_data *execute_data, zval *return_value`

I have php function which returns an array and it looks like this:
`

```
PHP_FUNCTION( myFunc ){ zval* myArray;
   array_init(myArray);
   /////
   zval_ptr_dtor( &return_value );
   *return_value_ptr = myArray;
}
```

How should I get similar functionalities without hanvig the `return_value_ptr`?
Should I use `#define RETURN_ARR(r)`?, If so how does this affect the performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PHP 7, most pointers to zvals (`zval*`) in PHP 5 have become plain zval structs (`zval`) - instead of passing around pointers to heap-allocated (`emalloc`) zvals, zvals themselves are copied. Because of this, in a sense,  `return_value` is the new `return_value_ptr`, because there's one less level of indirection everywhere.

So, to go through line-by-line:

---

Line 1:

```
zval* myArray;
```

In PHP 7, you don't hold a pointer to a zval, you put it directly on the stack. No external allocation. So the first line of your function should be instead:

```
zval myArray;
```

---

Line 2:

```
array_init(myArray);
```

`array_init` needs a pointer to a zval (`zval*`), so this should be:

```
array_init(&myArray);
```

---

Line 4:

```
zval_ptr_dtor( &return_value );
```

Again, PHP 7 removes a level of indirection here. It would just be this now:

```
zval_dtor(return_value);
```

However, you don't need this line in PHP 7. The zval doesn't need deallocating (in fact you can't deallocate it), you can simply overwrite it. You *would* need to use `zval_dtor();` if the zval contained a pointer to a string, array, or some other heap-allocated object, though. But in this case it's just a null, so you don't need to run it. Carrying on:

---

Line 5:

```
*return_value_ptr = myArray;
```

This should now be:

```
*return_value = myArray;
```

However, while you *can* directly overwrite `return_value` here, it is recommended to use the `ZVAL_COPY_VALUE` macro for this:

```
ZVAL_COPY_VALUE(return_value, &myArray);
```

Even better, you could use `RETVAL_ZVAL` which is a shortcut for setting the return value:

```
RETVAL_ZVAL(&myArray);
```

---

I should point out that you probably don't need the `myArray` zval in this case, as you can store the array in the `return_value` directly and save you having to copy it later. Another thing to bear in mind is that you should probably handle parameters. If you don't take any, `zend_parse_parameters_none();` is sufficient.

I suggest reading the [phpng upgrading guide](https://wiki.php.net/phpng-upgrading) and the [internals upgrading guide](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0/UPGRADING.INTERNALS).

Comment: You usually shouldn't assign raw zvals directly, so line 5 should be `ZVAL_COPY_VALUE(return_value, &myArray);`, or even better `RETVAL_ZVAL(&myArray);`.